# initializing and modifying C arrays of structs in Obj C

Tags: objective-c, c, struct, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to work with some Open GL stuff in iOS but I'm getting stuck up on the C stuff, which I haven't worked with in a decade.

The example code I'm using as a base declares struct Vertex:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
} Vertex;
```

Then, it declares a C-style array of vertices it uses for the math:

```
Vertex Vertices[] = {
    {{0.5, -0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{-0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}},
    {{-0.5, -0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}}
};
```

Rather than just use this fixed array, I need to call out to a method to return a new array of vertices, which is where I'm getting stuck. What I'm going for is something like (and I know this is completely wrong, it's more pseudo-code than anything):

```
- (Vertex (*)[])getLineSegments {
    Vertex *vertices = ?? //(need [allPoints count] Vertexs)
    for (int i = 0; i < [allPoints count]; i++) {
        vertices[i] = { [allPoints[i] getPoints], [allPoints[i] getColor] }; //how do I make a new Vertex in this fashion?
        //and then, in getPoints/getColor, how would I make a float[] and return that properly
    }
    return vertices;
}
```

Just trying to instantiate and assign values using malloc and things I've read elsewhere is failing miserably:

```
- (Vertex (*)[])getLineSegments {
    Vertex (*vertices)[4] = malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * 4);
    Vertex *point = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
    float Pos[3] = {0.5, -0.5, 0}; //error: Array Type Pos[3] is not assingable
    point->Position = Pos;
    float Color[4] = {1,1,1,1};
    point->Color = Color;
    vertices[0] = point;
    vertices[1] = {{0.5, 0.5, 0} , {1, 1, 1, 1}};
    vertices[2] = {{-0.5, 0.5, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1}};
    vertices[3] = {{-0.5, -0.5, 0},{1, 1, 1, 1}}; //errors... errors everywhere
    return vertices;
}
```

How do I do this properly?

### ---

edit: Updated to the following from Burton's advice. Still some errors:

```
- (Vertex (*)[])getLineSegments {
Vertex (*vertices)[4] = malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * 4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    vertices[i] = malloc(sizeof(*vertices[i])); //err: Array type 'Vertex[4]' is not assignable 
    vertices[i]->Position[0] = 0.5; //this one works. is this correct?
    vertices[i].Position[1] = -0.5; //Member reference type 'Vertex *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use ->?
    vertices[i].Position[2] = 0;
    vertices[i].Color[0] = 1;
    vertices[i].Color[1] = 1;
    vertices[i].Color[2] = 1;
    vertices[i].Color[3] = 1;
}
return vertices;
}
```

Comment: It compiles, but I doubt it does what you want. I will publish a piece of code that I think achieves what you want shortly. If it works, I can describe where things went wrong in your code. Are you by any chance a java programmer. The patterns you use suggest that

Comment: So, in C, when you allocate malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * 4), you actually allocate 4 Vertex, unlike java, where you would have allocated only 4 references that need to be filled with Vertex themselves. Once you think about it like this, I hope it will make more sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to create a single dimensional array of type `Vertex`, is this correct?

If this is the case your `getLineSegments` could look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    float Position[3];
    float Color[4];
} Vertex;

typedef Vertex * VertextPtr;

VertextPtr getLineSegments() 
{
    VertextPtr vertices = (VertextPtr)calloc(sizeof(Vertex), 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
        vertices[i].Position[0] = 0.5;
        vertices[i].Position[1] = -0.5;
        vertices[i].Position[2] = 0;
        vertices[i].Color[0] = 1;
        vertices[i].Color[1] = 1;
        vertices[i].Color[2] = 1;
        vertices[i].Color[3] = 1;
    }
    return vertices;
}

int main(void)
{
    VertextPtr vertices = getLineSegments();

    printf("Position: %f\n", vertices[2].Position[0]);
    printf("Position: %f\n", vertices[2].Position[1]);
    printf("Position: %f\n", vertices[2].Position[2]);
    //
    // Do clean-up here.
    return 0;   
}
```

Note that I used a `typedef` on the `Vertex *` to make the code a little cleaner. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually assign the values.  The notation you are using is only for automatic variables.  It won't look as nice, but that's pretty much the only way to initialize dynamic data.  Like so:

```
vertices[1].Position[0] = 1;
vertices[1].Position[1] = 2;
vertices[1].Position[3] = 3;
vertices[1].Color[0] = 1;
vertices[1].Color[1] = 1;
vertices[1].Color[2] = 1;
vertices[1].Color[3] = 1;
```

and so on for each of vertices[2], and vertices[3].

Oh, and you have to do

```
vertices[1] = malloc(sizeof(*vertices[1]));
```

first to allocate storage for the data.

Comment: Wow, ok. Does the malloc allocate the arrays inside the struct as well?

Comment: I've updated the original post with your advice, but still getting some errors. Can you take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would sugget (even though I used a variable instead of 4). Assuming I understand what you want to do.

```
Vertex *getLineSegments(int size) {
    Vertex *vertices = malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        vertices[i].Position[0] = ...;
        vertices[i].Position[1] = ...;
        vertices[i].Position[2] = ...;
        vertices[i].Color[0] = ...;
        vertices[i].Color[1] = ...;
        vertices[i].Color[2] = ...;
        vertices[i].Color[3] = ...;
    }
}
```

And then the way you call this method:

```
Vertex *vertices = getLineSegments(4);
```

--OR--

```
Vertex vertices[] = getLineSegments(4);
```